# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 2 is out of range

Tags: java, sql-server, exception

I have following code in Java

```
qry="insert into usr_auth(usrid,username,password,email) values(?,?,?,?)";
            ps=con.prepareStatement(qry);
            ps.setString(1,getUniqueID());
            ps.setString(2,newUp.getUsrName());
            ps.setString(3,newUp.getPwd());
            ps.setString(4,newUp.getEmail());
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

This code is giving me an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as:

> Database Exception Occured
>
> We are sorry for inconvenience
>
> Exception Details: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
> The index 2 is out of range. Details:
>
> The index 2 is out of range.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 2 is out of
> range. at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:700)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setValue(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:709)
> at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setString(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1034)
> at DBOps.addUser(DBOps.java:55) at RegUser.doPost(RegUser.java:13) at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641) at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:286)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:272)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1730)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
> Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
> Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

In the database I have 4 columns `usrid, username, password, email`. `username` is of `nvarchar(MAX)` type.

Everything seems fine but I am still getting this exception - why?

The line 55 in the stack trace is the line `ps.setString(2,newUp.getUsrName());`

Comment: usrid is char(6) n all others are nvarchar(max) in database but in java class files they are String. But usrid has no relation with username. Its giving error in username.

Comment: What value you using for username???

Comment: Check if the result of `getUsrName()` is NULL.

Comment: @tvanfosson: ya I checked, its not null...

Comment: i think in database you are declare lenght of the field and here you are enter more than that data lenght

Comment: In database I declared username as nvarchar(MAX) and whenever I am giving a 10 length username from my page it is giving the error. Can u tell me how much nvarchar(MAX) can store?

Comment: The problem is likely that `ps` is a field in your `DBOps` class, and gets overwritten by a concurrent request. Without a [mre] that is not really possible to verify though.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to your issue but it is possible to get this error if you miss a single quote somewhere when using XQuery within SQL.  I had this with the following SQL:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET CustomFields.modify('replace value of (/CustomFields/Field[@ID=1]/Value)[1] with "HELLO WORLD!") WHERE ID=?
```

It needed to be

```
UPDATE TABLE SET CustomFields.modify('replace value of (/CustomFields/Field[@ID=1]/Value)[1] with "HELLO WORLD!"') WHERE ID=?
```

(single quote missing after with "HELLO WORLD!")

So the exception in my case was the wrong exception thrown by the SQL driver.